# Calculating AWS snapshot usage cost programatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am planning to calculate snapshot usage cost using a script.

As per the documentation if we have GB-month value we can calculate the cost based on this. Is there any way to calculate snapshot size and its age? I could not find any method to fetch the snapshot size. When I describe a snapshot I do get `volume-size` in snapshotInfo but I don't think that's the snapshot size. Also the age of a snapshot is not defined in the description. Only the timestamp when the snapshot was initiated is in the output.

I don't want the cost for all the snapshots. I will be filtering snapshots based on a custom tag. I saw https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cost-allocation-for-ebs-snapshots/ but this is via the UI and needs special permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The cost and usage report is the *only* way to capture this information.  It is not accessible through the service API.

EBS snapshots are -- logically -- the same size as the source volume, because every EBS snapshot contains a reference to a stored representation of every single block on the volume.

But it's only a reference -- a pointer -- because EBS doesn't store the actual data blocks inside the snapshot itself.  It maintains a mapping and has the ability to determine which blocks are unchanged from snapshot to snapshot, so that it doesn't redundantly store them.

The price you pay for a given snapshot is directly determined by how many blocks in that snapshot are different from those in the most recent, prior snapshot of the same volume that still exists.  Deleting older snapshots preserves any blocks that are still needed for restoring newer snapshots, and thus rolls the cost of those blocks forward into snapshots that still exist, with the cost shifting into the oldest snapshot that still needs the blocks after any older ones are deleted.

So the cost of a given snapshot changes as previous snapshots of the same volume are deleted.

Also:

> Only the timestamp when the snapshot was initiated is in the output.

That's the age.  Snapshots are snapshots -- an image of the disk at the moment in time the snapshot was initiated.  Regardless of how long the snapshot takes to run, the data it captures is the data as it existed on the volume when the snapshot was initiated.

Comment: So if I multiply size of volume and total time snapshot has been active that will give me GB-month required to calculate the billing cost?

Comment: That is only true if the snapshot is the only snapshot in existence for the volume, and if each block on the volume has had data written to it, ever.  Otherwise you will always come up with a cost that is much higher than reality.  The cost and usage reports are the only place to actually find this information.  You can configure these reports to be automatically and continually be exported to an S3 bucket for later processing.

Comment: And there is no API way to get the number of blocks in use in S3 at any particular point of time? If there is a S3 bucket which only contains only the snapshots can I not find the total blocks in use there to calculate the cost?

Comment: Correct, there is not.  The bucket that EBS stores snapshot fragments in is owned by the EBS service -- it's not a bucket accessible to you.  You'll also notice on billing that EBS (EC2) charges you for the storage, not S3.